# What can I read to learn the history of multivariable calculus?

Tags: mathematics, calculus, linear-algebra

People have been doing calculus of several variables since well before the concepts of vectors, matrices, and linear algebra were formalized. Where can I learn about the development of multivariable calculus?

Comment: Briefly, here: [MathOverflow, History of calculus of several variables](https://mathoverflow.net/q/156075), and in a book form, here: [Crowe, A History of Vector Analysis](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_History_of_Vector_Analysis/iVFAVqA91h4C?hl=en&gbpv=0).